# Mylyn connector for custom webservice

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

I need Mylyn connector to communicate with my custom webservice. We have our customized bug tracker system and I want to link it with Mylyn task repository. I am able to create custom webserivce which can return specific kind of result to link with Mylyn connection.

Anyone have idea about such connector which allow you to connect with custom webservice?

I know about web connector but it has limited capabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to implement your own connector implementation possibly based on existing other implementations (The Redmine or Mantis connector come to mind).

That includes providing both a core and ui plugin at least. Reading the Eclipse Wiki might give you a good starting point: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_Integrator_Reference

Comment: Thanks Torsten, I am very new to plugin development do you have anything that can help in development? I appreciate your help

Comment: As said above you should probably start with looking at the existing sources for a similar bug tracker. The Eclipse Wiki holds a lot of useful information, I added a link in the answer.